# Firebase auth using email/Password signs user anonymously

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Fetching sign-in methods for email returns `EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID` (Password), but when trying to sign-in with the same email using `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and even that the returned task is successful, it signs-in the user anonymously, and `getCurrentUser().getProviders()` returns an empty Array.

```
   instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail("registredEmail@mail.com")
            .addOnSuccessListener(task -> {
                List<String> signInMethods = task.getSignInMethods();

                if (signInMethods.contains(EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)) {

                    instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword("registredEmail@mail.com", "password")
                            .addOnSuccessListener(task1 -> {
                                FirebaseUser currentUser = instance.getCurrentUser();

                                Log.i("", "IsAnonymous: " + currentUser.isAnonymous());
                                Log.i("", "Email: " + currentUser.getEmail());
                                Log.i("", "Providers is Empty: " + currentUser.getProviders().isEmpty());
                            });
                }
            });
```

Output

```
 IsAnonymous: true
 Email: helptesting@mail.com
 Providers is Empty: true
```

Please note that this code won't certainly reproduce the issue, the issue is maybe environnement/configuration related, but, the combination of email/password is valid and does exist in the Firebase auth dashboard, besides, tasks are successful, but user is signed-in anonymously and no provider is returned (Expecting password provider)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimal, complete code that is needed to reproduce the problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn why and how to do this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Code edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been addressed by Firebase. It was a lib issue.